# $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x \tan x}{\sec x \tan x} d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I have solved the Q. Answer in my textbook is $-2\pi + x $ but I got $-1$. So , I want to confirm my answer and understand where I have done mistake.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x \tan x}{\sec x \tan x} d x$$
$$\left.\implies \int_{0}^{\pi}(x \cos x) d x=\int_{0}^{\pi} x \sin x+\cos x+C\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow \pi \sin \pi+\cos \pi+C-0-C$$
$$\Rightarrow \pi[0]+(-1)$$
$$=-1$$

Comment: In general $\int_a^bf(x)dx\ne f(b)-f(a)$. But the answer in the book does not make sense. A definite integral with the integration variable $x$ should not yield an answer that contain $x$.

Comment: @Andrei Hmm K. Where should I correct myself ? Any link reference I can use

Comment: I would do [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) with $u=x$, $v'=\cos x$, so $u'=1$ and $v=\sin x$

Comment: @Andrei I checked & edited & tried again. Pls check now.

Comment: Note that your integrand is not defined on the interval of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\pi x\cos x dx=x\sin x|_0^\pi-\int_0^\pi\sin x dx\\=x\sin x|_0^\pi-(-\cos x)|_0^\pi=(x\sin x+\cos x)|_0^\pi\\=(\pi\sin \pi+\cos\pi)-(0\sin 0+\cos 0)=-1-1=-2$$